# how to compare JSON data with array localy

Tags: javascript, json

I have some objects within my script:

```
var data =
[
            {
            "name":"United Kingdom",
            "countryCode":"GB",
            "urlCode":"en-gb",
            "standardPrice":"30"
        },{
            "name":"Germany",
            "countryCode":"DE",
            "urlCode":"de-de",
            "standardPrice":"22"
        }

];
```

I would like to compare the "urlCode" to an array that I already have lets say its called array1

I would like to access these data above and compare it to my array, to say if this array matches the urlCode in the data, show all the objects inside the data of the one thats matched.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```js
var data =
[
            {
            "name":"United Kingdom",
            "countryCode":"GB",
            "urlCode":"en-gb",
            "standardPrice":"30"
        },{
            "name":"Germany",
            "countryCode":"DE",
            "urlCode":"de-de",
            "standardPrice":"22"
        }

];
var arr =["de-de"];
data.forEach((o) =>{
  if(arr.includes(o.urlCode))
    console.log(o);
});
```

Comment: if you will pass data[0 it will always return the first object., try the following:  var index  =  data.findIndex((o) => arr.includes(o.urlCode));  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = '<div>' + data[index].standardPrice + '</div>'

Answer (score -3):

You can compare element by element as the following:

```
your_array = ['en-gb','de-de']
data = [
            {
            "name":"United Kingdom",
            "countryCode":"GB",
            "urlCode":"en-gb",
            "standardPrice":"30"
        },{
            "name":"Germany",
            "countryCode":"DE",
            "urlCode":"de-de",
            "standardPrice":"22"
        }
];
isEqual = True
for i in range(0,len(data)):
    if  data[i]['urlCode'] != your_array[i]:
        isEqual = False
        break
print isEqual
```

Comment: This is NOT even the right language, the OP is asking for Javascript solution.

Comment: it asked for PYTHON in the beginning

Comment: Oh well, I'll remove my downvote when I can, sorry, but the solution is still useless.

Comment: It says you need to edit, before I can change the vote, if you add a disclaimer that you were anwsering the original question

Comment: Even in the edit history of the original question, python is not mentioned. I'm not sure where you saw it at.

Comment: I searched python in question and got this one. Hope this can help you being more sure.

Comment: thanks all but i never asked for Python not sure where that was found. also dont get why my question is getting negative vote! im asking a question I didnt know how to resolve myself. this is just childish.